# Make same format between server and client

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, client, date-format

How can I make same format of date between server and client. My server's date format is yyyy/mm/dd. But the client's date format is dd/mm/yyyy. When the model post to server, the system cannot bind date from client form data because of client's date format. Please see sample code below.

In Controller

```
 Function TestDateFormat() As ActionResult

        Dim testDateFormatVM As New TestDateFormatVM

        testDateFormatVM.FormatDate = New Date(1989, 8, 22)

        Return View(testDateFormatVM)

    End Function
```

In Model

```
Public Class TestDateFormatVM


    Public Property FormatDate As DateTime


End Class
```

In View

```
@ModelType ListTest.TestDateFormatVM

@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "TestDateFormat"
End Code

<h2>TestDateFormat</h2>


@Using Html.BeginForm("Display", "Home")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(item) item.FormatDate)

    @Html.HiddenFor(Function(item) item.FormatDate)

    @<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
End Using
```

Before form submission, the date of hidden field was updated form javascript with "dd/mm/yyyy" dateformat. When the form posts to server, the model gets error due to wrong datetime format because the server format is mm/dd/yyyy.

I would like to know what is the best way to make same date format between server and client until server culture is changed.

Thanks all

Comment: Code/HTML example please? What type of control are you using?

Comment: Hi TrueBlueAussie, I was updated my question. Thanks for response.

Comment: You should use ISO format for dates and times when posting values to the server: yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss